# Generating arrays inside for loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the two following variables:

```
$contact_number=array('0123456','65321');
$msg="My Text" ;
```

I am trying to create an array like following using the above variables

```
$myarray =array(
       array("0" => "0123456", "1" => "My Text"),
       array("0" => "65321", "1" => "My Text")
 );
```

I have tried the following code but it is not creating the exact array live above:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($contact_number); $i++ ) {
      $myarray[] =array(array("0" =>$contact_number[$i], "1" =>$msg),);
  }

 var_dump($myarray);
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through every contact number, and append a message like this:

```
$contact = array('0123456','65321');
$message = "My Text" ;

$array = array();

foreach($contact as $value) {
    $array[] = array($value, $message);
}

var_export($array);
```

Produces this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '0123456',
    1 => 'My Text',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '65321',
    1 => 'My Text',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and making the code easier/smarter :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append the new array values:

```
  $myarray[] = array("0" => $contact_number[$i], "1" => $msg);
```

The double nesting `array( array(0=>.., 1=>..) )` was redundant, because assigning using `$array[] =` already creates a new subarray.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#~square+bracket+syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
$contact_number=array('0123456','65321');
$msg="My Text" ;

foreach($contact_number as $key => $number) {
    $my_array[] = array($key => $number, $key+1 => $msg);
}
var_dump($my_array);
```

the above will result

> array (size=2)
>
> 0 =>
>
> ```
> array (size=2)
>
>   0 => string '0123456' (length=7)
>
>   1 => string 'My Text' (length=7)
> ```
>
> 1 =>
>
> ```
> array (size=2)
>
>   1 => string '65321' (length=5)
>
>   2 => string 'My Text' (length=7)
> ```

screw my internet connection, someone already answered ..